# MySQL: Display number of records based on 2 columns with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following columns..

```
Name, pageID, promoID

Bob, 123, promo1
Steve, 123, promo1
Nancy, 123, promo2
Lyn, 123, promo2
Amy, 123, promo2
Jeff, 123, promo2
Joe, 456, promo3
Bill, 456, promo3
Joe, 456, promo3
```

I want to create a report of only records that have pageID of 123 and then group them by promoID. So my table output would look like this..

```
Records for pageID 123..
promo1 = 2 entries
promo2 = 4 entries
```

What query would accomplish this?

Here's what I currently have spitting out into an HTML table..

```
$querysubmissions = mysql_query("SELECT promoID FROM submissions WHERE fbPageID = '123'");
$numbersubmissions = mysql_num_rows($querysubmissions); 


$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions WHERE fbPageID = '$page_id' GROUP BY promoTitle");

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $title = $data['promoTitle'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$title.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$numbersubmissions.'</td>'; 
    echo "<td><a href='submission-csv.php?promoid=".$data['promoID']."'>Export</a></td>";
    echo '</tr>';
    }

    mysql_close();
```

But this just returns the total number of submissions for the 123 pageID and all promoIDs. And how would I echo this out in PHP?

Comment: Well yes, you haven't told the query to group your results.

Answer (score 5):

Try `GROUP BY` in your select and use `count(*)`:

```
SELECT promoID, count(*) as `count`
FROM submissions 
WHERE fbPageID = '123'
GROUP BY promoID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$querysubmissions = mysql_query("SELECT promoID,COUNT(promoID) as count FROM submissions WHERE fbPageID = '123' GROUP BY promoID");
$numbersubmissions = mysql_num_rows($querysubmissions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of this in the sql query itself.

```
Select PromoID, Count(PromoID) as pCount From submissions where fbPageID = '123' Group By PromoID
```

You can also do this for more than one page

```
Select concat('Page ',fbPageID,', ',PromoID,' = ',Count(PromoID)) as result From submissions Group By fbPageID, PromoID
```

This has the added bonus of not needing to do a select for each page. so your results would look like

```
Page 123, Promo1 = 2
Page 123, Promo2 = 4
Page 456, Promo3 = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Ths query will display in the 'promo1 = 2 entries' format

```
SELECT 'Records for pageID 123' ResultDisplay
UNION
SELECT
    CONCAT(promoID,' = ',cnt,' entr',IF(cnt=1,'y','ies'))
FROM
    (SELECT promoID,count(1) cnt 
    FROM submissions  
    WHERE pageID = '123' 
    GROUP BY promoID) A;
```

Here is your sample data loaded into a submissions table:

```
mysql> use junk
Database changed
mysql> drop table if exists submissions;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.02 sec)
mysql> create table submissions
    -> (name varchar(10),pageID int,promoID varchar(10)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into submissions values
    -> ('Bob'  , 123 , 'promo1'),
    -> ('Steve', 123 , 'promo1'),
    -> ('Nancy', 123 , 'promo2'),
    -> ('Lyn'  , 123 , 'promo2'),
    -> ('Amy'  , 123 , 'promo2'),
    -> ('Jeff' , 123 , 'promo2'),
    -> ('Joe'  , 456 , 'promo3'),
    -> ('Bill' , 456 , 'promo3'),
    -> ('Joe'  , 456 , 'promo3');
select * from submissions;Query OK, 9 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 9  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from submissions;
+-------+--------+---------+
| name  | pageID | promoID |
+-------+--------+---------+
| Bob   |    123 | promo1  |
| Steve |    123 | promo1  |
| Nancy |    123 | promo2  |
| Lyn   |    123 | promo2  |
| Amy   |    123 | promo2  |
| Jeff  |    123 | promo2  |
| Joe   |    456 | promo3  |
| Bill  |    456 | promo3  |
| Joe   |    456 | promo3  |
+-------+--------+---------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is execution of the query:

```
mysql> SELECT 'Records for pageID 123' ResultDisplay
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT
    ->     CONCAT(promoID,' = ',cnt,' entr',IF(cnt=1,'y','ies'))
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT promoID,count(1) cnt
    ->     FROM submissions
    ->     WHERE PageID = '123'
    ->     GROUP BY promoID) A
    -> ;
+------------------------+
| ResultDisplay          |
+------------------------+
| Records for pageID 123 |
| promo1 = 2 entries     |
| promo2 = 4 entries     |
+------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Give it a Try !!!

Here it is in PHP

```
$givenpageID = 123;
$sql = "SELECT 'Records for pageID " . $givenpageID . "' ResultDisplay UNION SELECT CONCAT(promoID,' = ',cnt,' entr',IF(cnt=1,'y','ies')) FROM (SELECT promoID,count(1) cnt FROM submissions WHERE PageID = '" . $givenpageID . "' GROUP BY promoID) A";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["ResultDisplay"];
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: This looks great. Do you know how I would echo each row in PHP?

Comment: I added the PHP to fetch and display